# teechart 4 ocx doesn't run on win7

Tags: mfc, windows-7-x64, teechart, visual-c++-6, ocx

We have a problem with an old application which use teechart.ocx version 4.02 OCX release 4.0.0.7.

On my Win7 (64 bits) everything run without problem. But on the Win7 of my colleague (also 64 bits), the control does'nt appears.
Of course we have registred the ocx (within admin cmd shell).

To be sure that the problem does'nt come from our (old) application, we perform a test on both machine with the demo example which comes with Teechart.ocx (TeechartPro/Examples/VisualC++/Version6/TeeFiles).
On my PC everything runs well.... but on the other one, same problem : we get the application without the TChart control. 
And when we click the 'about' button, we get an error : debug assertion failed / winocc.cpp / line 345...

Is there anybody who can help ??????

Thank you

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason... it should be the MFC dlls and libs which are not exactly the same on each PC. They have the same name, but with different size & dates. 
Just recompile on the most recent environnment clears the problem 
Hope it can help